# Why do we use dynamic allocation in a linked list?

Tags: c++

In a linked list class, the code below is declaring `Node<T> *newNode`:

```cpp
void LinkedList<T>::push_front(const T& val) {
    Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>(val);
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
    if(newNode->next == NULL) tail = newNode;
}
```

Why do we use dynamic allocation? Can't we just write `Node<T> newNode(val);`?

I think since we are not making arrays of `newNode`, it is valid.

Comment: I think we can aslo change the following codes : newnode->next to newnode.next

Comment: the list store a pointer to a  Node, the object pointed has to be "valid" for the lifetime of the list. If you store a pointer to  a local variable, destroyed at the end of the function, you are storing a pointer to an object which will be invalid soon, much before the list lifetime ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local variables such as `Node<T> newNode(val);` would be destroyed when exiting the function (or rather, when exiting the scope (aka braces, more or less)) that it was created in.

But for a linked list, you want the nodes to live longer; as long as you want them to.

Comment: It's a really clear explanation. Thank you so much.